# Как обрезать строку в jq? (не работает в ie11)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция, отлично работает во всех браузерах кроме ie. 
подскажите что не так....

```js
function findItemResult() { 
  var activeInput = district.find("input:checked");
    arr = [];
    activeInput.each(function( index ) {
      item = $(this).attr("id");
      arr.push(item.substring(10,18));
    });
    return arr; 
};
```

В ie ошибка: Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод substring.
substr(), slice() аналогично.

Comment: а длина строки "id" у всех элементов больше 10 и меньше 18 символов?

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас в `this` и `item` в момент возникновения исключения.

Comment: длина строки всегда попадает в этот диапазон

Comment: в this и item данные приходят правильные

Comment: @Vital, перед `item` `var` поставьте ...

Comment: да, все верно. Спасибо!

Comment: тогда уж и перед `arr` тоже можно поставить :)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, хорошего понемногу xDDD